# call to column gives row vector instead of column vector python

Tags: python-2.7

Hey im making a loop where I have to repeatedly update a column vector X estimate by adding another column to the X estimate, however whenever i'm calling a Column in this x estimate it givers me a row vector and I Cannot redefine the output row as a column using vstack because then I will no longer be able to plug it in at the start of the loop where it is needed for new calculations

Below the output for my xestimate

```
Xest = [[ 0.      0.   ]
        [ 1.      1.   ]
        [ 1.      1.0001]
        [ 1.      1.0001]]
```

later on the call 'Xest[:,0]'
output >> '[0 1 1 1]'

however i need it to be a column,

```
'[[0],  [1],  [1  [1]]'
```

I dont really understand with the call [:,0] it should be a column should it not?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understand `Xest` is a numpy array.

Quick answer:
You can obtain what you want with `np.vstack(Xest[:,0])` or, better, `Xest[:,0][:, np.newaxis]`

Slightly longer answer:
Why do you want to do that? Most of the time, you don't, and just rely on broadcasting to do it for you. There is no such a thing as "column vector" in numpy, so most cases can be handled with a normal "row vector". For those corner cases where you do need a distinction, you can make a view and play with the strides, as `[:, np.newaxis]` does.

Full justification:
Imagine you have an array of 10 dimensions, and you want one vector. Do you really want an array that is like `[[[[[[[[[[1, 1, 1, 1 ...]]]]]]]]]]`? Numpy is meant to work with arbitrary dimensions, and therefore, designed for the general case.